# Installing python module on remote server

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if there was a way to install and use BeautifulSoup (or any python module for that matter), which is not provided by my hosting service, without root privileges?

Comment: Use [virtual environments](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can install package without root privilege.

use pip with '--user' option. Then pip install package in your '~/.local/' folder.

```
pip install --user some_package
```

if you use setup.py or easy_install, they also provide similar feature. (installation on user folder or changing installation root folder)